# Okay so I am trying to a rownum into a variable but I need it to give me only one value, so 2 if it's the second number in the row

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
   select rownum into v_rownum
    from waitlist
    where p_callnum=callnum
        order by sysdate;
```

tried doing this but gives too many values.

and if I do `p_snum=snum`, it will keep returning 1. I need it to return 2 if it's #2 on the waitlist.

```
 select rn into v_rownum
from (select callnum, 
    row_number() over (order by sysdate) rn
    from waitlist)
where p_snum=snum;
```

Almost got it to work. Running into issues in the first select. I believe I might have to use v_count instead. Also Ordering by Sysdate even if a second apart will order it correctly.

```
    SNU    CALLNUM TIME
--- ---------- ---------
101      10125 11-DEC-18
103      10125 11-DEC-18
```

BTW time is = date which I entered people into waitlist using sysdate. So I suppose ordering by time could work.

create table waitlist(
  snum varchar2(3),
  callnum number(8),
  time date,
  constraint fk_waitlist_snum foreign key(snum) references students(snum),
  constraint fk_waitlist_callnum foreign key(callnum) references schclasses(callnum),
 primary key(snum,callnum)
);

is the waitlist table.

Comment: `order by sysdate`? `sysdate` is the same for all rows, as it's just the current time, so you are not ordering your rows at all.

Comment: What does `#2 on the waitlist` mean? Which column indicates the order to make you consider the row second?

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO` works only when the count of returned rows is exactly 1. Thus `rownum` will always return 1, and this is meaningless - you can just use 1 instead of query.

Comment: so I can't use a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

I used Scott's `DEPT` table to create your `WAITLIST`; department numbers represent `CALLNUM` column:

```
SQL> select * From waitlist;

   CALLNUM WAITER
---------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH
        30 SALES
        40 OPERATIONS
```

How to fetch data you need?

- using analytic function (`ROW_NUMBER`) which orders values by `CALLNUM`s, you'll know the order
- that query will be used as an inline view for the *main* query that returns number in the waitlist for any `CALLNUM`

Here's how:

```
SQL> select rn
  2  from (select callnum,
  3               row_number() over (order by callnum) rn
  4        from waitlist
  5       )
  6  where callnum = 30;

        RN
----------
         3

SQL>
```

Comment: ohhhhhh this makes so much sense. I can do order by sysdate where P_snum=snum to get what number in the row it is.

Comment: all right So I'm trying to translate this into plsql. I want to put that into v_rownum. ` select rn into v_rownum
 from (select callnum, 
        row_number() over (order by sysdate) rn
        from waitlist)
 where p_snum=snum;`

Comment: This is very close. Just need to do where snum=p_snum; which is fine but I can't get it to fit into the variable.

Comment: If you can't make it work, edit your question (the first message you posted here), provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data, explain which result you'd want to get from it. Because, I have no idea what SNUM is nor what you should do about it.

Answer (score 0):

rownum in oracle is a generated column, it does not refer to any specific row, it is just the nth row in a set.

With a select into it can only return one row (hence the two many rows error) so rownum will always be 1.

Without more details about your table structure, and how you are uniquely identifying records it is hard to give assist you further with a solution.

Comment: Was just using SNUM CallNum and Sysdate, I suppose I have to use count in order to get the waitlist number. The table is ordered by sysdate.

Comment: time date. Basically. But those are all the date in waitlist table. I just need to fetch what rownum a student is in the waitlist table.